# How to add extra param on best_in_place field update in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I am using **best_in_place** gem for **In-line** edit for a field in active admin. Please look at my code below,

```
column "Badge ID", :number do |event|
   best_in_place event, :number, :type => :input, :path => [:admin, event]
end
```

This is what the parameters sent to the controller action.

**Parameters: {"event"=>{"number"=>"499"}, "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxx", "id"=>"995"}**

Now, I want to send additional parameter along with the number either inside or outside the event hash.

Anyone, Please help me resolve this.

Comment: This goes to controller's update method.

Comment: Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did.

```
column "Badge ID", :number, :sortable => 'event_category_registrations.number' do |event_category_registration|
   best_in_place event_category_registration, :number, :type => :input, :path => update_admin_event_category_registrations_path(:id=>event_category_registration.id,:event_id=>event_category_registration.try(:event_id)) #, :path => [:admin, event_category_registration]
end
```

Please note the changes in "Path" attribute. Hope this helps.

Comment: With so many people using this gem you wonder why there are so few examples.. Thanks for the update!! It helped me